# How to check that all items of a list are equal to a given value?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a function that checks that all items of a list are equal to a given value. The function should take a list of strings, returning `True` if every string is exactly `"car"`, and `False` otherwise.

```
*Main> go ["car","car","car"]
True

*Main> go ["car","car","bus"]
False
```

This is my current implementation but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
go :: [String] -> Bool
go ("car":[]) = True
go ("car":xs) = False
go _ = False
```

Comment: `go ("car":xs) = False` is wrong. If the first element of the list is "car", can we really say "not all of them are 'car'"? You need to recurse instead.

Comment: What about the empty list?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. Doesn't matter the first element is car or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `go ("car":xs) = False` means that a list that contains as first item `"car"` and has at least one extra item (since the pattern before covers the case of a singleton list) should return `False`. You should recurse on the list, so the function should look like:

```
go :: [String] -> Bool
go ("car" : xs) = …
go (_ : _) = False
go [] = True
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` part, this should make a recursive function call.

You can however implement `go` with [**`all:: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
go :: Foldable f => f String -> Bool
go = all ("car" ==)
```

Comment: The second one works but I need the first one must work. I didn't understan the "..." part.

Comment: @YavuzhanCanli: that is the part you still need to fill in, with the text in the answer giving hints how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

These are what you get from your code:

- with `go ("car":[]) = True`, you get

  `go ["car"] -> True`
- with `go ("car":xs) = False`

`("car":xs)` is a pattern matching that captures a list of the form `["car",...]`, so you will get

```
go ["car"]        -> False   -- not used because the first case takes priority
go ["car", "car"] -> False   -- INCORRECT
go ["car", "bus"] -> False
go ["car", ...]   -> False   -- NOT ALWAYS CORRECT
```

- with `go _ = False`

`_` is a pattern matching that captures any list, so you will get

```
 go []             -> False
 go ["car"]        -> False  -- not used because the first case takes priority
 go ["bus"]        -> False
 go ["car", ...]   -> False  -- not used because the second case takes priority
 go [...]          -> False
```

You can get a correct answer with

```
 go [] = True                       
 go ("car":xs)  = ...
 go _ = False
```

but you need to fill ... with something that depends on xs (the tail of the list).
The head (first element) of `("car":xs)` is already equal to `"car"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to avoid this?

```
Prelude> go = all (=="car")
Prelude> go ["car", "car", "car"]
True
Prelude> go ["car", "car", "bus"]
False
```